# Rxjs - Tap isn't triggered by subscribe in concatMap()

Tags: rxjs

I have a Subject that maps an observable, I subscribe to the observable in the concatMap but it doesn't trigger tap() from the subscription.

```
this.streamA$ = this.streamService.getStream(1)
      .pipe(
        tap(data => console.log('stream data:', data))
      );
```

Subject

```
this.images$ = this.queue.pipe(concatMap((event: Observable<string>) => {
      // when an event arrives here it is still wrapped in observable

      // subscribe isn't triggering tap()
      event.subscribe(data => {
        //console.log('inner observable subscription:', data);
      });

      // observable goes to the image$ observable, it is unwrapped by: image$ | async in template
      return event;
    }));
```

Service function

```
  getStream(time: number): Observable<string> {

    let timer$ = timer(2000);
    console.log('get stream');

    const observable = new Observable<string>(observer => {

      timer$.pipe(
        map(() => {
          observer.next('http response 1');
          observer.complete();
        })
      ).subscribe();

    });
    return observable;
  }
```

---

Update:

```
event.subscribe(data => {
         //console.log('inner observable subscription:', data);
      });
```

Without console.log included in subscribe this is the output:

```
stream data: http response 1
```

With console.log, prints these 3 lines at the same time:

```
stream data: http response 1
inner observable subscription: http response 1
stream data: http response 1
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have an Observable inside a `concatMap`, you don't need to subscribe. Could you try something along these lines?

```js
this.images$ = this.queue.pipe(
  concatMap(event => event), // I assume the event here is something like this.streamA$
  tap(data => // do stuff with data)
);
```

Comment: I know I was just wondering why tap isn't triggered twice though

Comment: Because the source Observable isn't emitting anything. If you want it to emit its latest value when new observers subscribe, use `BehaviorSubject`.

Comment: Confusing :S what is event in the concatMap, a stream in progress? What is being subscribed to when subscribing to event?

Comment: Actually I just realized, the way you've written must leak all over the place (unless `event` completes, of course). You're subscribing again and again to an Observable, never destroying the previous subscription…

As for why it doesn't hit the `tap`, it's because it was an emission from the Observable that triggered the new subscription. Therefore, nothing is emitted _after_ that inner subscription. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: It looks like the tap is actually working, I'll do a stackblitz. When I subscribe to the event in concatMap it does trigger additional streams.